# Why isn't my push to git working on my Bootstrap template?

Tags: html, css, git, github

I am new to Bootstrap templates as well as Git. I made a github.io site, but when I pushed my code to git and open my site, my formatting is all wrong. When I open it through my browser, it looks how I want it to. Why isn't it formatting properly? What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

**Check your project for below scenario**

- Check and confirm you push to proper `Branch`
- Check `.gitignore` file from your project `root` directory

**Example**

> `PATH\TO\YOUR\PROJECT\.gitignore`

**`.gitignore` file is look like**

```
/vendor/*
/tmp/*
/logs/*
/img/downloads/*
```

> That mean `git` will not push those files to your remote `branch`.

If `.gitignore` file have some directory to skip `git` tracking, Then remove the directory/files to allow tracking

After done! Try below command from your git command line.

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Type Your Commit Message Here"
```